# How to implement UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter for email field instead of username in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, servlet-filters

There is UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in SpringSecurity itself but I want to use email instead of username.
I had used this class for username like this :

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private JwtUserDetailsToUserDTOConverter jwtUserDetailsToUserDTOConverter = new JwtUserDetailsToUserDTOConverter();

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override 
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override 
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {


        String token = JwtGenerator.builder().build().generate((JwtUserDetails) authResult.getPrincipal());



        response.addHeader(JwtConstants.HEADER,JwtConstants.PREFIX + token);
    }



}
```

I want to implement AuthenticationFilter for email and password. There is no any specified class for this intent inside of SpringSecurity.
How can I customize it for email?

Answer (score 2):

- UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter just extracts username (which could be email) and password from request and forwards it to the configured [AuthenticationManager](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.x-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html).
- The default (assuming you haven't overridden it), implementation of AuthenticationManager used is [ProviderManager](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.x-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html).
- ProviderManager in turn is configured with an [AuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). This would be DaoAuthenticationProvider in most cases.
- From DaoAuthenticationProvider, call reaches [UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername-java.lang.String-) which tries to look up a user from DB based on given username.

So you have couple of options here:

1. Create a custom UserDetailsService, with overridden loadUserByUsername(), which matches the given username against user's email. This can then be set into `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` instance like this:

   ```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception            
       {    
           auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Custom AuthenticationProvider which validates user against email. This is a bit of an overkill for your scenario and would result in duplication of code. But if you want to do this, use the same code as #1 but invoke `auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthProviderInstance);` instead